# Magnitude responses of parametric equalizer

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, matlab-figure, audio-processing

I am trying to combine several freqz plots which relates to magnitude responses of parametric equalizer filters in MATLAB. I based my function equalizer on formulas from audio-processing book. The problem is that I don't know how to make plots which vertex will go up, and not only down (how it is now),

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Joshua_Reiss/publication/302067841/figure/fig13/AS:667906585141254@1536252747583/Magnitude-responses-of-low-frequency-shelving-filters-with-complementary-gains-12-dB.png
where the plots are going both up and down. Which variable I am supposed to change to make it look like this, or if something is wrong with the code, how can I fix it?

```matlab
%%%FUNCTION
function [num1,den1] = equalizer(G0,G,w,delta_w)
%G0 - gain 1
%G - gain 2
%w - center frequency
%delta_w - bandwidth 
GB = sqrt(G0*G); %gain parameter
beta = sqrt((GB^2-G0^2)/(G^2-GB^2))*tan(delta_w/2);
beta = tan(delta_w/2);
num = [(G0+G*beta)/(1+beta); ((-2*G0*cos(w))/(1+beta)); ((G0-G*beta)/(1+beta))]';
den = [1; ((-2*cos(w))/(1+beta)); ((1-beta)/(1+beta))]';

num1 = num;
den1 = den;

end

%%%SCRIPT
figure;
freqz(equalizer(1, 0.6, pi/2, pi/4)); hold on 
freqz(equalizer(1, 0.2, pi/2, pi/4)); hold on
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the vertex to go up by adjusting the `gain 2` parameter.  The figure below shows values of 4.8, 2.4, 1.2, 0.6, and 0.2.  Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Have you looked at the [freqz documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html) to be sure that you're plotting what you intend?

Comment: first of all, thank you for the answer:) and not so sure, the one that you posted has 'round' shape, and from what I know, the shape is supposed to look like the one that has the vertex going down

Comment: Can you add the description from the book where you got your filter function?

Comment: I just edited the question because i added a new line of code (gain parameter), this is what i am trying to achieve (what they did in the book):  
In Figure 10.5 some examples of magnitude responses of parametric equalizer
filters are shown for varying gains, G. The filters shown all have a center frequency of ω0 = π/2, a bandwidth of ∆ω = π/4 with GB =sqrt(G*G0) and G0 = 1, and this figure has both up and down plots

Comment: Have you tried reproducing exactly the parameter values in the book?  Also, I can't see Figure 10.5